# R Quandl Error, No Daily

Tags: r, quandl

```
Quandl("CHRIS/CME_CL1", trim_start=Sys.Date()-15, trim_end=Sys.Date()-10, collapse="daily")
Error in match.arg(collapse) : 
  'arg' should be one of “”, “weekly”, “monthly”, “quarterly”, “annual”
```

Any ideas why that wont work? I copied straight from website too..

Comment: There is no `daily` argument available for option `collapse`.

Comment: how can one get daily data then, or is there no daily data available?

Comment: Ask the [maintainer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Quandl/index.html) maybe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer.

Initially when I created the package I saw no need to support daily since by default the data returned is the most granular, which in our case is daily. However I have seen some confusion arising lately and it won't hurt to accept it. I will accept "daily" as a parameter on the next release.

This should work right now

```
Quandl("CHRIS/CME_CL1", trim_start=Sys.Date()-15, trim_end=Sys.Date()-10)
```

Comment: Hello @Ray, may I ask how to get the SEC Harmonized Data into r ?
I tried Quandl("RAYMOND/MSFT_COSTOFREVENUE_Q", trim_start="2009-06-27", trim_end="2014-03-29") but with no luck.